# How do you change a pure-ftpd virtual-users username/login?

Tags: ftp, pureftpd

I have `pure-ftpd` running on my server and I want to change just the username for some of my `virtual-users`. Is this possible?

I've looked in the documentation and the man page for `pure-pw` and it doesn't seem to be mentioned. I also tried Google but nothing came up that was related.

If so will the passwords and other settings remain the same? Or do I need to set those up again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up working this out myself and thought I'd share the steps below...

---

If you're using the `pureftp.passwd` file to manage your virtual-users then follow these steps:

1. Backup `pureftp.passwd` first before making any changes. Mine was in `/etc/pure-ftpd/`.

   > $ cd /etc/pure-ftpd/
   >   $ cp pureftp.passwd pureftp_backup.passwd
2. Open the `pureftp.passwd` file with your favourite editor e.g. `nano` or `vi`.

   > $ nano pureftp.passwd

   The beginning should be similar to this:

   > username1:@!#*HKnkasd ...
   >   username2:G(*asHJKY#$ ...
3. Edit the usernames and save the file.
4. Next you need to rebuild the pure-ftpd user database:

   > $ pure-pw mkdb
5. Test the changes.

> **NOTE**: Note you might need to prepend 'sudo' to the commands depending on your user access. Also you do not type the '$' sign in the above commands. It's purely indicative of your shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

## For me work it:

1) Install pure-ftpd

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
```

2) Add group for virtual users

```
sudo groupadd ftpgroup
```

3) Add ftp user for virtual user

```
sudo useradd -g ftpgroup -d /dev/null -s /etc
```

4) Enable ChrootEveryone option

```
sudo echo on > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone
```

5) Enable the virtual user authentication

```
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/40PureDB
```

6) And restart pure-ftpd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

7) Create the user dir

```
mkdir /home/ftp/joe
```

8) Change the owner/group to the ftp user

```
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpgroup /home/ftp/joe
```

9) Create user joe with home directory /home/ftp/joe

```
pure-pw useradd joe -u ftpuser -d /home/ftp/joe
```

10) Write changes to the database

```
pure-pw mkdb
```

**UPDATE:**

***How to change an existing pure-ftpd Virtual username:***

1) Go to password file (in my case - ubuntu server):

```
sudo nano /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd
```

2) Change the user name for example:

An existing (user name josecarlosold):

> josecarlosold:$1$ITkf2XA0$imFzCWux1rsnPieBlEttQ0:1001:1001::/home/josecarlos/./::::::::::::

NEW (user name josecarlosnew):

> josecarlosnew:$1$ITkf2XA0$imFzCWux1rsnPieBlEttQ0:1001:1001::/home/josecarlos/./::::::::::::

3) Re-make the pure-ftpd DB:

```
sudo pure-pw mkdb
```

4) Open your ftp client and try connect with the new username `josecarlosnew` and the same password that `josecarlosold`. Remember `josecarlosold` and `josecarlosnew` are user to explant.

[Reference](https://blog.bruin.sg/2013/06/pure-ftp-and-virtual-user-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to _change_ an existing pureftp users username.

Comment: Opss, Sorry, I update right now.